# Silent Install VSTO addin

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I created an VSTO Outlook app for my job. The thing is, we need to deploy that to users without any user interaction, so in other words, silently.

I know that we can use `VSTOinstaller.exe` located in `%commonprogramfiles%\microsoft shared\VSTO\9.0\` and use it like so in a command line `VSTOinstaller.exe /install "Path_to_the_VSTO_file" /silent`.

But when I do this, nothing happens, no error message and no install.
However If I remove the `/silent` arg, it launch the VSTO and prompt me if I want to install the app.

I tried changing the arg with `/I`, `/i`, `/S` or `/s` but nothing change.

My app is sign with a valid cert and when we get prompt, we can see the green logo

I've look at many threads about silent install for that, but it's always the same.

Do I do something wrong? Is there any other way to do that silently?

Thank you!